# How to Access Java Map variable in JSP

Tags: jsp, dictionary, struts2

I have defined a Map Variable in Action Class in prepare Method, and I need to loop through this Map variable in JSP Scriptlet to get the key and value. But I to get this Map Variable in JSP. Is there a way to just get the Map object in JSP directly i.e. From Action Class to JSP Scriptlet????

Below is my prepare method:

```
@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
 securityMenu = new HashMap<String,String>();
 securityMenu.put("userGroupMaster","Group Master");
 securityMenu.put("userProfileMaster","Profile Master");
 securityMenu.put("userTypeMaster","User Type Master");
}
```

I want this securityMenu in JSP Scriptlet Like:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> map : securityMenu.entrySet()){
    out.println( "eLK('e1d1L1','i','"+map.getValue()+"','"+map.getKey()+"');");
}
```

Any help would be a great help for me

Comment: I wouldn't use a scriptlet (bad practice).  I would use ´<s:iterator>´ and other struts2 provided tags.  As long as you have a getter or if it is in the session you should have access.

Comment: Wrap it within `<℅℅>`

Comment: Thanx for the response... Actually I am populating Menu Items using CSS, that is why I am using Scriptlet. How to get this session variable in JSP Scriptlet and assign to an Variable in JSP Scriptlet??

Comment: Populating menu using css? Are you sure? ;)

Comment: Yes I am using JavaScripts to Populate Menus, can you give me a struts2 example to do so??

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have a `getSecurityMenu()` method.

Next you could this in the jsp:

```
<s:iterator value="securityMenu">
    <s:property name="key"/>
    <s:property name="value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

If the map is in the session under the name `securityMenu`, you could do as follows:

```
<s:iterator value="#session.securityMenu">
    <s:property name="key"/>
    <s:property name="value"/>
</s:iterator>
```

EDIT:
For this to work your page must declare the following Struts2 taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

Comment: Thanx for the response... Actually I am populating Menu Items using CSS, that is why I am using Scriptlet. How to get this session variable in JSP Scriptlet and assign to an Variable in JSP Scriptlet?? –

Comment: @Shubhankar You can't definitely popupate anything with CSS. Maybe you are populating your menu with JAVASCRIPT, and that can be done with Scriptlets (bad) or with Struts Tags (best) or with JSTL (good). But in the end, if you are loading your menu items with javascript during the loading of the JSP, there is even no need to use javascript: just generate your HTML with Struts tags inside an iterator directly. You are overcomplicating a simple thing in at least two different ways...

Comment: Yes I am using JavaScripts to Populate Menus, can you give me a struts2 example to do so??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like normal javacode in scriptlets.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : securityMenu.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue();
}
```

**However**, *scriptlets* (raw Java code in JSP files, those `<% %>` things) are considered a poor practice. I recommend to install JSTL (just drop the JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` and declare the needed taglibs-3 in top of JSP). It has a  tag which can iterate over among others `Map`s. Every iteration will give you a `Map.Entry` back which in turn has `getKey()` and `getValue()` methods.

Here's a basic example:

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:forEach items="${securityMenu}" var="entry">
    Key = ${entry.key}, value = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Got the Solution I set securityMenu in session and in JSP I get like : Map<String,String> arrayMenuSecurity = (Map<String,String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("securityMenu");